# Do java script or jquery has a function like inArraykey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexing

As far as I know jQuery has a function `inArrary` which is apply like the following

```
$.inArray(value, array); it return -1 if not in array
```

However, this function only apply to value and is not suitable for the multidimension array

```
eg . fruit [ apple,orange]
```

For instance, if I have an array like this

```
eg. fruit [apple => [red,$1], orange => [orange,$5]]
```

I have to check whether a value exist (eg. banana) as the array key, are there any function appropriate in this case?

Comment: your question/example is not really clear. Are you referring to indexOf() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays cannot have string keys in JavaScript. Only objects can.

If you want to see if an object contains has a key `banana`, you can simply test that it isn't `undefined`:

```
if (myObject.banana != undefined) {

}
```

... or use `hasOwnProperty`, which may be better in cases when you may have initialized a property to `undefined`:

```
if (myObject.hasOwnProperty("banana")) {

}
```

Comment: I'd use `'banana' in myObject`. Also, I'd use `!== undefined`, as `myObject.banana` can be `null`.

Comment: *"Arrays cannot have string keys"* - but they can have properties since they are still objects :)

Comment: really helpful, that's all I want

Comment: You should go with `hasOwnProperty` - not having a property is not the same as that property existing and being undefined.